# Error: /apex/lightningAccountLayout: Syntax error and Syntax Error

Tags: page-layout, compile-error

***I'm running into these two errors and am not sure why. Any suggestions?***

- Error: /apex/lightningAccountLayout: Syntax error
- Error Error: Syntax error

***I'm new to SF, and just learning Apex. I'm also going through the Trailhead course for this, but the code below looks okay to me..***

```
     
</apex:page>
<apex:page standardController="Account">
  <apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.styleforAccountLightningPage}"/>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
  
  
  <p>{!IF(CONTAINS(Account.Systems_Pick__c,"Medication Dispenser"), 
      '"Medication Dispenser Device Number: " + {Account.MED_Device_Number__c}', false)}</p>

       
     
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single apostrophes are incorrect, as well as the extra curly brackets. You put the entire formula in `{!...}`, and there should be no extra curly brackets anywhere. Also, string concatenation is & in Visualforce. Finally, you can't mix return types in an IF statement (string versus Boolean). Use an empty string instead.

```
  <p>{!IF(CONTAINS(Account.Systems_Pick__c,"Medication Dispenser"), 
      "Medication Dispenser Device Number: " & TEXT(Account.MED_Device_Number__c), '')}</p>
```

Comment: Very helpful in explination and example! However, I'm receiving this error with the changes above: 'Error: Incorrect parameter type for operator '&'. Expected Text, received Number'

Comment: @AlexisFrisch So, `TEXT(Accout.MED_Device_Number__c)`. I'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

This was the code that worked

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">

  <apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.styleforAccountLightningPage}"/>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
  
  
 <p> {!IF(CONTAINS(Account.Systems_Pick__c,"Medication Dispenser"), 
      "Medication Dispenser Device Number: " & TEXT(Account.MED_Device_Number__c), '')} </p>
     
</apex:page>
```

The error I received above was because the Account.MED_Device_Number__c was a number and not a string. Putting TEXT() around it, solved the error.

Code works great!

Huge shoutout to @sfdcfox for assisting and explaining so well!

Comment: My apologies for the previous comment. I thought you edited the question. It's perfectly fine to add your own answer when it's a self-Q&A, although standard etiquette states you should accept/upvote the provided answer rather than adding your own when someone else answers your question.

Comment: So sorry! I will figure out how to do that - Very new at this!